# pip3 not working in OpenSuse 42.3 | No module named '_socket'

Tags: python, linux, pip, installation, opensuse

I have OpenSuse 42.3, in which there is a python2.7 in `/usr` and I have compiled python3.6 from source in `/usr/local`

python3 works fine.

I need to install other packages like numpy, pandas with pip.

I found pip3 is there in `/usr/local/bin/pip3` with command `which pip3`

but when I try to run any command with pip3 **(For example `pip3 --version`)**, it fails saying this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 7, in <module>
    from socket import error as SocketError, timeout as SocketTimeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_socket'
```

Comment: did you try installing in `/usr`?